# Oral contraceptive sales in the USA, especially Washington DC and Maryland

Tags: data-request, usa, economics, medical

I have an emergency department hospital admission data-set for deep vein thrombosis (DVT). Oral contraceptive use is a risk factor for DVT. I would like to correlate oral contraceptive sales with hospital admissions for DVT.

Therefore I am looking for data on contraceptive (particularly oral) sales in the USA. If specific data on sales in Washington DC and Maryland is available this would be ideal.

Comment: Market research companies must have the sales data. But if you want it fast and free, use Google Trends on respective queries.

Answer (score 1):

I would be *extremely* leery of relying upon Google Trends as a reliable indicator of sales of pharmaceuticals. Trends measures simply search interest, not product adoption.

Instead, a good indicator for what you're looking for may be found in data from [Medicaid.gov](https://www.medicaid.gov/), which details [highly-localized prescription data](https://www.medicaid.gov/medicaid/prescription-drugs/state-drug-utilization-data/index.html) of all residents enrolled in Medicaid. While this isn't a perfect solution –– it only accounts for medicaid recipients –– it should give you a more precise idea, especially if you can find a way to control for Medicaid prescription rates vs. general RX rates.